# Is it Possible to Overload SQL Server Functions?

Tags: sql-server, functions

Is it possible to overload a sql server function? Either a scalar, like ltrim, or an aggregate function, like count?

Even if this was a really, really, bad idea. Is it possible?

Somewhat of a duplicate of [T-SQL User defined function overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050700/t-sql-user-defined-function-overloading) I would say it isn't 100% a duplicate, since that was for 2005 version. Maybe this has changed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no straight-forward way of carte-blanche overriding a built-in function in SQL Server.

You can *kind of* fake it by creating a function with the same name in a different schema, then calling that function *with the schema name*, as in:

```
SELECT dbo.COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.SomeTable st
GROUP BY st.SomeCol;
```

However, this is quite likely to cause more confusion than it is worth.

Comment: And if you're going to have to change the code to use the schema name anyway, you might as well change it to refer to a differently-named user function.

Comment: Completely agree, @BradC - overall it's just a bad idea to try overloading in SQL Server.